# How do I return HTML (the content type, not just the string) from a WebApi endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, content-type

This is an endpoint in ASP.NET WebApi2 where I want the content type returned as a HTML document.  This currently returns it as text/plain.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetHtmlPreview(int id, bool isHtml)
    {
        var msg = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><h2>TEST HTML STUFF HERE" + id + "</h2></body>"),
        };
        return msg;
    }
```

I want it to return as text/html so it renders fine within an iFrame.

Comment: At this point you probably just want a standard MVC controller. - API controllers should be used to return data, not HTML.

Comment: yes, normally i would return from a MVC controller, but the way the current app is, this needs to be a GET hanging off the very same endpoint, so I needed to still use ApiController versus a new MvcController

Comment: Seems Fishy, Why would it NEED to be a GET from the same endpoint? Im not sure I am following you... sounds like a code smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `ContentType` like so:

```
msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
```

I do agree with BenjaminPaul in that a View backed by your controller seems like a better approach here.

Comment: Yep, agreed.  For brownfield reasons, I still needed to add it to an existing endpoint.  Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
public IResult Function()
{
    return Results.Text("your_html_string", contentType: "text/html");
}
```